# Can't import class from nexus repository(spring boot + maven) in Mac M1?

Tags: java, spring-boot, nexus

I have private Nexus repository and I deployed a `common-service` to Nexus with pom.xml:

```
<groupId>vn.edu.fpt</groupId>
    <artifactId>common-service</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.5</version>
    <name>common-service</name>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <description>common-service</description>
    <url>http://vn.edu.fpt.common-service</url>
    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>
...
<plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.2.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>attach-sources</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>jar-no-fork</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>11</source>
                    <target>11</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <distributionManagement>
        <snapshotRepository>
            <id>nexus-snapshots</id>
            <url>http://localhost:8081/repository/maven-snapshots/</url>
        </snapshotRepository>
        <repository>
            <id>nexus-releases</id>
            <url>http://localhost:8081/repository/maven-releases/</url>
        </repository>
    </distributionManagement>
```

But when I try to add dependency for this repository, I can't import class from `common-service` even I see the library `vn.edu.fpt:common-service` has been downloaded.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VUpTa.png)

Comment: I tried with Win 11 and its success. But same library I can't import in Mac M1

Comment: Hi Harley, i am facing similar issue, library is downloaded but I see similar error like yours. Did you make any changes to remove the error?

Comment: Sorry, I still can't solve this problem. I switched to using win instead of mac m1. Maybe mac m1 is not compatible and need some advanced settings